# Why is an iptables rule needed on Oracle CN to allow HTTP traffic on port 80, when no reject rule is set and the default policy is set to ACCEPT?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, linux-networking, oracle-cloud

I have an Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Compute Node on the free tier, configured with Ubuntu 22.04 as the operating system. I successfully installed Nginx and added an ingress rule to the subnet to allow internet connections on port 80.

However, I'm facing an issue where I can't access the server by entering the public IP in the browser. After some research, I discovered that I need to add iptables rule(s) to allow HTTP traffic on port 80. Once I add the rule(s), the server becomes accessible. I found to ways to do this:

By adding this rule:

> sudo iptables -I INPUT 6 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j
> ACCEPT sudo netfilter-persistent save

Or by adding these two rules:$

> sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate
> NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
>
> $ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate
> ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

I'm puzzled by the fact that I couldn't access the server from outside without adding the rule(s), even though the default INPUT policy is set to ACCEPT and I couldn't find any reject rule specifically blocking port 80.

Before adding the rule, I have used the command: sudo iptables -S, and I got the following result:

> -P INPUT ACCEPT
>
> -P FORWARD ACCEPT
>
> -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
>
> -N InstanceServices
>
> -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
>
> -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
>
> -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
>
> -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
>
> -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
>
> -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
>
> -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
>
> -A OUTPUT -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j InstanceServices
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.2/32 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images
> section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security
> impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.2.0/24 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images
> section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security
> impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.4.0/24 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images
> section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security
> impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.5.0/24 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images
> section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security
> impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the
> Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of
> modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the
> Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of
> modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the
> Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of
> modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.3/32 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images
> section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security
> impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the
> Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of
> modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the
> Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of
> modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the
> Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of
> modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 69 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the
> Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of
> modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the
> Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of
> modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.0/16 -p tcp -m tcp -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or
> removing this rule" -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
>
> -A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.0/16 -p udp -m udp -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or
> removing this rule" -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

The default policies for INPUT, FORWARD, and OUTPUT chains are set to ACCEPT. The only rule that points to port 80 for a specific ip is set to active as well.

Question: Shouldn't this be enough for the server to be accessible? What am I missing?

Please explain the whys and hows in a simple way as I am a begginer. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I can see REJECT targets in both INPUT and FORWARD chains right there. These will match any traffic. Am I missing a reason why these shouldn't apply in your case? But anyway, having a restrictive set of rules while opening the required services only is good practice, so keep it the way it is.

Comment: @Zdenek Yes! Thank you! After conducting further research, I was able to understand that all packets will be blocked unless they are accepted with specific rules. I was confused with the first policy rules, P INPUT ACCEPT.

Comment: @DRA the policies apply if there are no rules that match. But if there are rules that explicitly match, then that rule applies.

Comment: @pepoluan Thank you! Is it possible to delete the policies lines (three first lines) and keep the rest? Will that change something? will it even work?

Comment: @DRA I don't remember what the default policies for iptables are. I think they're `ACCEPT`, so yes explicitly setting `-P ACCEPT` is not doing anything.